# Java - 3 or More Distinct Numbers

Tags: java, arrays, distinct-values

In my code, the user enters how many numbers they want to test, and then enters the numbers. If a number can be divided by 3 distinct numbers, it prints a "1". Otherwise, it prints a "0". When I run my code, it only prints "0". I tried fixing some of the brackets to see if messed up somewhere in the syntax.

```
            int distinct = 0;
            int T = input.nextInt();
            int [] nums = new int [T];

            for (int n : nums) {
                distinct = 0;
                n = input.nextInt();
                for (int m = nums.length; m == 0; m--) {
                    if (n % m == 0) {
                        distinct++;
                    }
                }
                if (distinct < 3) {
                    System.out.println("0");
                }
                else
                    System.out.println("1");
                }
            }
        }
```

By "three distinct numbers", I mean a number like "4" which can be divided by "4, 2, and 1".

When I enter this:

```
3
2 3 4
```

It returns:

```
0
0
0
```

When it *should* return:

```
0
0 
1
```

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop, you initiate the variable with `int m = nums.length`.

As the length of `nums` is defined at the beginning by the user as 3, the first factor you check is 3 before checking all positive integers less than this. So, for `n = 4` you check 3, 2 and 1; only 2 and 1 are factors so distinct will be 2. I suspect this should be `int m = n`;

```
for (int m = n; m == 0; m--) {
    if (n % m == 0) {
        distinct++;
    }
}
```

Assuming you are ignoring negative integers (as this would mean negative integers could be considered), the only time this will fail is when n is 1 or n is prime; 1 and n itself will always be a factor. As such, you could ignore the check for these values.